# Memcached passing data using php

Tags: php, caching

I have installed memcached 1.4.4-14 on my windows systems. I have started the service and everything is in order. Now all I am trying to do is test it using .php which is served using IIS.

So I right a basic index.php page and browse through IIS. I can render the page and general .php works. Its just nothing happens with the memcache. There is so much confusion out there about what pre-requisites I need to install. I can't fathom which ones are essential. The PHP I installed is a new clean install with only the php_memcache.dll extensions dumped in .php.

It is worth noting that in phpinfo I can see no reference to memcache.

Would love some basic assistance.

Here is my example that I am using, I believe it is the standard test for memcache session dump.

```
session_start();
header("Content-type: text/plain");
$memcache = new Memcache;

$memcache->connect("localhost",11211); # You might need to set "localhost" to "127.0.0.1"5
echo $memcache->get(session_id());
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in using compression, please note that, at least for PHP version 5.3.2 and Memcache version 3.0.4, when retrieving a key who's value is a numeric or boolean type, PHP throws a notice of the following:

Message: MemcachePool::get(): Failed to uncompress data

The way around this is to test your variable type before setting or adding it to Memcache, or even cast it as a string.

```
<?php
$key = 'mc_key';
$value = 12345;
$compress = is_bool($value) || is_int($value) || is_float($value) ? false :             MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED;

$mc= new Memcache;
$mc->connect('localhost', 11211);
$mc->set($key, $value, $compress);

echo $mc->get($key);

//Alternative is to cast the variable
$value = is_scalar($value) ? (string)$value : $value;
$mc->set($key, $value, MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED);
?>
```